# What is the network topology symbol for a KVM switch?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse, visio, network-design, network-topology

I've been tasked with putting together some network diagrams in Visio and we have some IP-based KVM switches that need to be captured.  I've been relying on the [Cisco Network Topology Icons](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac50/ac47/2.html) for the rest of the architecture, and would like to continue to do so, but there doesn't seem to be an icon for KVM switches (IP-based or otherwise).  I don't mind creating a new stencil (in the event there isn't already one available for Visio), but it would be nice to know what it's supposed to look like before starting down that road.  Is there a standard symbol for KVM switches on network diagrams, and if so what is it?

Thanks.

Note:  To clarify, I've got plenty of stencils for creating rack elevations.  The issue is using standard symbology for creating network diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can find one here:

http://www.visiocafe.com

Comment: I've done some poking around there, but it's not very well indexed.  I'll keep looking, though.

Answer (score 1):

http://community.emerson.com/networkpower/support/avocent/kvmip/m/mediagallery/2248.aspx should do the trick. All I did was `google://ipkvm+stensil`

Comment: I was looking for Cisco-style network symbology such as is found in http://www.visiocafe.com/downloads/vsdfx/VSDfx-Network-Symbols-3D.zip.  The problem appears to be there is no such standard icon for IP based KVM switches.

Comment: because cisco don't manufacture those